# Groovy JsonSlurper and nested maps

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have a method that returns fairly-nested JSON such as:

```
[[fizz: buzz, foos: [[count: 4, flim: flam], [count: 6, flim: flume]]]]
```

When I try to use `JsonSlurper` to slurp this JSON into a `def result` I am getting exceptions:

```
// json == “[[fizz: buzz, foos: [[count: 4, flim: flam], [count: 6, flim: flume]]]]"
String json = getJSON()
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()

def result = slurper.parseText(json)
```

Produces an exception thrown when `parseText` executes:

```
Caught: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
```

Any ideas what the fix is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to use Groovy's map notation as JSON.  JSON uses curlies for maps, like this

```java
import groovy.json.*

def obj = [["fizz": "buzz", "foos": [["count": 4, "flim": "flam"], ["count": 6, "flim": "flume"]]]]
def json = JsonOutput.toJson(obj)
assert json == '''[{"fizz":"buzz","foos":[{"count":4,"flim":"flam"},{"count":6,"flim":"flume"}]}]'''
def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
```