# Gradle sync failed - unable to determine the current character

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am currently unable to build project.

```
Current error:

Script '/Users/pimzonneveld/the-red-corner/veganific-mobile-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 191
Gradle sync failed: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
            The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
            Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
            line number 1
            index number 0
            info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.
            ^ (6 s 386 ms)
```

Tried deleting `app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json` which doesn't work.

Tried removing `.gradle` and `.idea` and resyncing with Android Studio. Didn't work.

Tried removing and reinstalling `@react-native-community` package

Tried removing

Android Studio is `V3.5`
Gradle is `V5.4.1`

**EDIT**

The file which is currently failing is `native_modules.gradle` posted below:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings

def generatedFileName = "PackageList.java"
def generatedFilePackage = "com.facebook.react"
def generatedFileContentsTemplate = """
package $generatedFilePackage;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

{{ packageImports }}

public class PackageList {
  private Application application;
  private ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost;
  public PackageList(ReactNativeHost reactNativeHost) {
    this.reactNativeHost = reactNativeHost;
  }

  public PackageList(Application application) {
    this.reactNativeHost = null;
    this.application = application;
  }

  private ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return this.reactNativeHost;
  }

  private Resources getResources() {
    return this.getApplication().getResources();
  }

  private Application getApplication() {
    if (this.reactNativeHost == null) return this.application;
    return this.reactNativeHost.getApplication();
  }

  private Context getApplicationContext() {
    return this.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
  }

  public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(){{ packageClassInstances }}
    ));
  }
}
"""

class ReactNativeModules {
  private Logger logger
  private Project project
  private String packageName
  private DefaultSettings defaultSettings
  private String root
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> reactNativeModules

  private static String LOG_PREFIX = ":ReactNative:"

  ReactNativeModules(Logger logger) {
    this.logger = logger
  }

  void applySettingsGradle(DefaultSettings defaultSettings, String root) {
    this.defaultSettings = defaultSettings
    this.root = root
    this.reactNativeModules = this.getReactNativeConfig()

    addReactNativeModuleProjects()
  }

  void applyBuildGradle(Project project, String root) {
    this.project = project
    this.root = root
    this.reactNativeModules = this.getReactNativeConfig()

    addReactNativeModuleDependencies()
  }

  /**
   * Include the react native modules android projects and specify their project directory
   */
  void addReactNativeModuleProjects() {
    reactNativeModules.forEach { reactNativeModule ->
      String nameCleansed = reactNativeModule["nameCleansed"]
      String androidSourceDir = reactNativeModule["androidSourceDir"]
      defaultSettings.include(":${nameCleansed}")
      defaultSettings.project(":${nameCleansed}").projectDir = new File("${androidSourceDir}")
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds the react native modules as dependencies to the users `app` project
   */
  void addReactNativeModuleDependencies() {
    reactNativeModules.forEach { reactNativeModule ->
      def nameCleansed = reactNativeModule["nameCleansed"]
      project.dependencies {
        // TODO(salakar): are other dependency scope methods such as `api` required?
        implementation project(path: ":${nameCleansed}")
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the user's project root (i.e. where the node_modules dir is located).
   */
  File getReactNativeProjectRoot() {
    File androidRoot

    if (this.project) {
      androidRoot = this.project.rootProject.projectDir
    } else {
      androidRoot = this.defaultSettings.rootProject.projectDir
    }

    File rnRoot = new File(androidRoot, this.root)
    this.logger.debug("${LOG_PREFIX}Using React Native project root path '${rnRoot.toString()}'")
    return rnRoot
  }

  /**
   * Code-gen a java file with all the detected ReactNativePackage instances automatically added
   *
   * @param outputDir
   * @param generatedFileName
   * @param generatedFileContentsTemplate
   */
  void generatePackagesFile(File outputDir, String generatedFileName, String generatedFileContentsTemplate) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>[] packages = this.reactNativeModules
    String packageName = this.packageName

    String packageImports = ""
    String packageClassInstances = ""

    if (packages.size() > 0) {
      packageImports = "import ${packageName}.BuildConfig;\nimport ${packageName}.R;\n\n"
      packageImports = packageImports + packages.collect {
        "// ${it.name}\n${it.packageImportPath}"
      }.join('\n')
      packageClassInstances = ",\n      " + packages.collect { it.packageInstance }.join(",\n      ")
    }

    String generatedFileContents = generatedFileContentsTemplate
      .replace("{{ packageImports }}", packageImports)
      .replace("{{ packageClassInstances }}", packageClassInstances)

    outputDir.mkdirs()
    final FileTreeBuilder treeBuilder = new FileTreeBuilder(outputDir)
    treeBuilder.file(generatedFileName).newWriter().withWriter { w ->
      w << generatedFileContents
    }
  }

  /**
   * Runs a process to call the React Native CLI Config command and parses the output
   *
   * @return ArrayList < HashMap < String , String > >
   */
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getReactNativeConfig() {
    if (this.reactNativeModules != null) return this.reactNativeModules
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> reactNativeModules = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>()

    def cmdProcess
    def root = getReactNativeProjectRoot()
    def command = "node ./node_modules/react-native/cli.js config"
    def reactNativeConfigOutput = ""

    try {
      cmdProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, root)
      def bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmdProcess.getInputStream()))
      def buff = ""
      def readBuffer = new StringBuffer()
      while ((buff = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
          readBuffer.append(buff)
      }
      reactNativeConfigOutput = readBuffer.toString()
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      this.logger.warn("${LOG_PREFIX}${exception.message}")
      this.logger.warn("${LOG_PREFIX}Automatic import of native modules failed.")
      return reactNativeModules
    }

    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(reactNativeConfigOutput)
    this.packageName = json["project"]["android"]["packageName"]
    def dependencies = json["dependencies"]

    dependencies.each { name, value ->
      def platformsConfig = value["platforms"];
      def androidConfig = platformsConfig["android"]

      if (androidConfig != null && androidConfig["sourceDir"] != null) {
        this.logger.info("${LOG_PREFIX}Automatically adding native module '${name}'")

        HashMap reactNativeModuleConfig = new HashMap<String, String>()
        reactNativeModuleConfig.put("name", name)
        reactNativeModuleConfig.put("nameCleansed", name.replaceAll('/', '_'))
        reactNativeModuleConfig.put("androidSourceDir", androidConfig["sourceDir"])
        reactNativeModuleConfig.put("packageInstance", androidConfig["packageInstance"])
        reactNativeModuleConfig.put("packageImportPath", androidConfig["packageImportPath"])
        this.logger.trace("${LOG_PREFIX}'${name}': ${reactNativeModuleConfig.toMapString()}")

        reactNativeModules.add(reactNativeModuleConfig)
      } else {
        this.logger.info("${LOG_PREFIX}Skipping native module '${name}'")
      }
    }

    return reactNativeModules
  }
}

/** -----------------------
 *    Exported Extensions
 * ------------------------ */

def autoModules = new ReactNativeModules(logger)

ext.applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle = { DefaultSettings defaultSettings, String root = ".." ->
  autoModules.applySettingsGradle(defaultSettings, root)
}

ext.applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle = { Project project, String root = ".." ->
  autoModules.applyBuildGradle(project, root)

  def generatedSrcDir = new File(buildDir, "generated/rncli/src/main/java")
  def generatedCodeDir = new File(generatedSrcDir, generatedFilePackage.replace('.', '/'))

  task generatePackageList {
    doLast {
      autoModules.generatePackagesFile(generatedCodeDir, generatedFileName, generatedFileContentsTemplate)
    }
  }

  preBuild.dependsOn generatePackageList

  android {
    sourceSets {
      main {
        java {
          srcDirs += generatedSrcDir
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And where's your file that is failing?Could you post it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Added the failing file

Answer (score 0):

It's failing on line 191, which is:

`def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(reactNativeConfigOutput)`

I believe JSON you are trying to parse is invalid.

Might be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231974/groovy-jsonslurper-and-nested-maps)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that I'm not trying to parse anything myself, it's gradle which tries to do that. I don't think I can affect how gradle calls upon JsonSlurper()? Or should I use an older version of gradle?